# Header & Footer Logo

Tags: html, header, footer

How to move my footer logo like my header logo?
I want to create like this

```
-------------------------
|       __________      |
|______| HeadLogo |____ |
|      |_________ |     |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|    ______________     |
|---|   FootLogo   |----|
|    ---------------    |
|_______________________|
```

preview my web
https://db.tt/EsMHtRpF

my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="all">
<div class="middle">


</div>
<div class="top">
<img src="images/head.png" class="top-img"></img>

</div>

<div class="bottom">
<img src="images/foot.png"></img>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

my css

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round");

* {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

html, body {
    background-color:#b3924a;
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}

.all {
    max-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
    media:screen;
}

.top {
    background-color:#d7cc75;
    width:100%;
    height:9%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:1;
}

.top-img {
    position:relative;
    width:17%;
    height:auto;
    z-index:1;
    top:1em;
}



.bottom {
    background-color:#d7cc75;
    width:100%;
    height:7%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1;
}

.bottom img {
    width:25%;
    height:auto;
    z-index:1;
}
```

thank you :D

Comment: According to this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4vZAB/, everything looks fine and dandy. try adding the images and see how it looks

Comment: Yogi: thanks for revision my preview

Comment: anurupr: sorry,I mean footlogo between body and bottom, but thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/4vZAB/1/

You set the `overflow` style to hidden for `div.bottom` which means it will hide any overflow of the content within it.

so the "footlogo" being inside the `div` , if you try to change its position to between the `body` and `.bottom` elements it will be hidden from view

PS: I commented out the `overflow` style, you can uncomment it and see how it behaves

Comment: ooh I didn't know about that the overflow caused the trouble, thanks a lot, sorry I couldn't give you reputation but thanks I get new knowledge from you

Answer (score 0):

Give css as

```
Position:relative
```

to the footer logo and adjust according to u usin top, bottom,left,right

css

```
.bottom {
background-color:#d7cc75;
width:100%;
height:7%;
position:relative;
bottom:0px;
text-align:center;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:1;
}
```